# How to model Logical Expression using Protege OWL

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, rdfs, hermit

I have structure like below

[image]

Now I have some expression which states which Part combination is a valid one
like these
Logical representation:

```
(Part1_3 and Part2_A and (Part3_0 or Part3_1))
or 
(Part1_4 and Part2_B and (Part3_0 or Part3_1))
or
(Part1_3 and Part2_B and Part3_0)
```

How should I model this using Protege?

Also My intension to model is to find if given a combination is it valid or not?

for eg Part1_3 Part2_B Part3_1 is an invalid combo
also Part1-4 and Part2-B is also invalid

Comment: given the Open World Assumption in OWL I don't see such modeling as an appropriate task for OWL + inference - that's more a use case for SHACL, SheX or SPARQL

Comment: But permutations would be possible with SHACL? if yes can you help me with an example to solve it so it supports both the cases?